# Excel range usage question (cell error checking)

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, automation

I have the following error for every cell:
"the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe"
To duplicate the error:
I have to store this results that come from a Web services as strings array:
Sample: (3 by 3 array)

$402,568.03 26.2%   30,052

$107,719.59 7.0%    55,176

$81,370.35  5.3%    54,365

let values be the string array holding sample (string[,] values)
Let  r be the range to target (Excel.Range r)
If I do:
r.Value2 =  values;

I would like to know how to get rid of it. Any .net code will be great (C# or VB.NET)

Note:
1) Looping in every cell is not an option as the array can be quite big (100, 54) or (1024, 104). I have done and it does not have this error but the performance is very bad.

2) Disable the errors is not an option, because I do not have control over the client settings.

3) I notice that I use the conver to number context menu fix the issue, but it is possible to do it for the affeccted range programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

you can programmatically ignore errors on a per Cell basis. This can be accomplished by the following vba code:

```
<tableObject>.Range("Q1:Q1000").Errors.Item(<errorNo>).Ignore = true
```

where `<tableObject>` is the table your data is located and `<errorNo>` is one of the following error categories:

```
1 xlEvaluateToError
2 xlTextDate
3 xlNumberAsText
4 xlInconsistentFormula
5 xlOmittedCells
6 xlUnlockedFormulaCells
7 xlEmptyCellReferences
```

of course you can loop to disable all 7 error types

edit:

what about adding a subroutine to your excel-file in the first place using the above code and loops and calling this subroutine from vsto:

```
ThisWorkbook.Application.Run("Sheet1.SayHelloVBA")
```

does this work?

Comment: thanks, but your solution does not work for multi-cell and unfortunately I need a multicell solution because my app is a vsto app and any COM calls are expensive.

Comment: what about calling a subroutine doing the loops as suggested?

Comment: looping in every cell does not need this construct as it works ok, I am looking for a range solution not a cell solution