# How to validate Excel range that it has error/warning using .NET?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I want to validate range of excel worksheet (e.g. "A10:B20") to check that is it has error or NA value or not? How to do that in C#?

P.S. I find similar topic ([Excel range usage question (cell error checking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383370/excel-range-usage-question-cell-error-checking)) but that topic is not thing I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to check for the data type of the value held in the cell. If the data type is an Integer (Int32), then the value held is a CVErr value. To check for #N/A, the cell would be an Integer data type (not a Double!) holding the value -2146826246.

For more details, see the stack overflow question [How to know if a cell has an error in the formula in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424718/how-to-know-if-a-cell-has-an-error-in-the-formula-in-c/2425170#2425170).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.First read the data from the excel.Please see this stack over flow question. [Convert Excel Range to ADO.NET DataSet or DataTable, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458481/convert-excel-range-to-ado-net-dataset-or-datatable-etc). Then iterate each row from the data table like

```
    foreach (DataRow row in sheetTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in sheetTable.Columns)
        {
            // Check what ever you want to check
            if (row[column].ToString().Equals("Error") || row[column] ==null)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to validate data without import it to DataTable, did you have any other idea?